# Updating SQL database using VB in studios

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-update

I've done more research with the comments left and just some on my own, So the code for the button has changed but it still is not working.

The button itself refreshes the page so there is some movement but it seems that everything after that is not working. And I still cannot figure out why. Any additional help would be welcome.

```vb
     Sub EditChronology(Optional type As String = "", Optional CaseNumber As String = "00-000", Optional Key As String = "", Optional value As String = "")
        Dim ChronologyCase As String = Request.QueryString("CaseNumber")
        'Dim EditRecord As String = Request.QueryString("Key")
        'Dim MSDate As String = Request.QueryString("MileStoneDate")
        'Dim Narr As String = Request.QueryString("Narrative")

        Response.Write("<div class=""box box-success""><div class=""box-header with-border""><h3 class=""box-title"">Edit Case Chronology:  " & ChronologyCase & "</h3>" _
        & "<div class=""box-body no-padding""><form action=""portal.aspx?page=edit&CaseNumber=" & ChronologyCase & """ method=""post"" name=""editchron"">" _
        & "<table class=""input-group"">")
        Response.Write("<tr><th width=""15%"">Record Number</th><th width=""20%"">Milestone Date</th><th width=""65%"">Narrative</th></tr>")

        Try
            Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                Dim query As String = "Select TOP 50 * FROM Table WHERE CaseNumber = '" & ChronologyCase & "' ORDER BY MilestoneDate DESC"
                Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("EditChronTable")
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
                Dim rows As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
                Dim count As Integer = 0

                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Response.Write("<tr><td>")
                    FormInput("Key", "", 6, dr("Key"), True)
                    Response.Write("</td><td>")
                    FormInput("MSDate", "", 10, dr("MilestoneDate"))
                    Response.Write("</td><td>")
                    FormInput("Narr", "", 1500, dr("Narrative"))
                    Response.Write("</td>" _
                    & "<td><button type=""submit"" id=""btncedit"" runat=""server"" class=""btn btn-success btn-sm margin"" style=""float:right"">Edit Record</button></td></tr>")
                    '<input type = ""submit"" value=""Update"">


                Next

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Response.Write("</table>")
        Response.Write("</form>" _
            & "</div>" _
            & "</div>" _
            & "</div>")

        If btncedit Is btnSubmit Then
            Try
                Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                    Dim Sql As String = ""
                    Dim command As New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
                    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    Sql = "UPDATE [Table] SET [CaseNumber] = @CaseNumber, [MilestoneDate] = @MSDate, [EntryDate] = @EntryDate, [Narrative] = @Narr, [InputBy] = InputBy WHERE [Key] = @Key"
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    command.Parameters.Add("@CaseNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ChronologyCase
                    command.Parameters.Add("@MSDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MSDate
                    command.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtNow
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Narr", SqlDbType.NText).Value = Narr
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Key", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ChronologyRecord
                    command.Parameters.Add("@InputBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strUser
                    command.Connection = conn
                    Try
                        'conn.Open()
                        adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
                        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Finally
                        conn.Close()
                    End Try
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub FormInput(name As String, display As String, Optional size As Integer = 15, Optional value As String = "", Optional disabled As Boolean = False)
        Response.Write("<div class=""form-group"" id=""container" & name & """>" _
        & "<label for=""input" & name & """ class=""col-xs-3 control-label"">" & display & "</label>" _
        & "<div class=""col-xs-9"">" _
        & "<input type=""text"" class=""form-control"" id=""input" & name & """ name=""" & name & """ size=""" & size & """ value=""" & value & """")
        If disabled = True Then
            Response.Write(" disabled")
        End If
        Response.Write(">" _
        & "<input type=""hidden"" id=""curr" & name & """ value=""" & value & """>" _
        & "<span class=""help-block"" id=""error" & name & """></span>")
        Response.Write("</div>")
        Response.Write("</div>")
    End Sub
```

Comment: What you have currently is wide open to SQL Injection attacks. Obligatory [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) reference. You could use [SqlParameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) to pass in your parameter values with the correct data types instead of trying to build query strings with your data inline. What's probably happening at the moment is the date strings that you're injecting into your query are formatted differently than SQL recognizes. You wouldn't have that problem with SqlParameters receiving proper DateTime values.

Comment: Also, check the documentation of the [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) statement. You seem to be trying to use `VALUES (...)` in the `WHERE` clause, which is something normally associated with `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Thank you, this has given me a good bit to read, research, and play with this week. I think I'm making progress.